# Load multiple version of asm

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, jax-ws, wildfly-9

In my java ee project I have ws-client that generated by wsimport lib and it use asm 3.3.  I use another dependency that work with asm 4.1. I deploy war file in wildfly 9. Wildfly 9 has asm 3.3 as embedded module. I exclude asm module from wildfly to other dependency work but then web service client not work and give below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitLabel(org.objectweb.asm.Label)
```

Comment: It looks like a method was deprecated or modified between your asm libraries, double check your build path as you should be getting a build error, your build path might be set to use 3.3 but your deployment might be being deployed with 4.1 and thus the no such method error

Comment: I set it 4.1 in pom.xml and it work fine after wildfly startup but when I redeploy it without restart above error raised.

Comment: Then that's a strange one, I'd recommend you post something in the [JBoss Developer Forums](https://developer.jboss.org/welcome) and see if anyone there can help you get the answer to your question.  If they help you figure it out, add it as an answer below!